# Series with iterated log's: does it converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence

This came up in our office today. Let

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x & \mbox{if } x\leq 1 \cr x\cdot f(\ln(x)) & \mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Does this series converge?

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{f(n)} $$

Comment: This problem came up on a recent Putnam. The answer was that it diverges at a similar rate to the function $log_*$.

Comment: 2008 A4, except it had $f(x)=x$ for $x\le e$. Solution available at http://amc.maa.org/a-activities/a7-problems/putnam/-pdf/2008s.pdf